# AutoMapper to Convert an object with a string property to an object with a URI property

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a class

```
public class A
{
        public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
        public string URI { get; set; }
}
```

and another class

```
public class B
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
        public Uri URI { get; set; }
    }
```

I intend to create an object of B from an object of A, using AutoMapper, but because the datatype of URI is different, I do need to write some code. 
I was able to achieve what I wanted by writing

```
cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
                .AfterMap((src, targ) =>
                {
                    Uri uri;
                    Uri.TryCreate(src.URI, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);
                    targ.URI = uri;
                });
```

Would like to know if this is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works fine, but you could create a map for string and URI, using an `ITypeConverter`:

```
public class StringToUriConverter : ITypeConverter<string, Uri>
{
    public Uri Convert(string source, Uri destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        Uri.TryCreate(source, UriKind.Absolute, out destination);
        return destination;
    }
}
```

> Depending on the situation, if you were mapping to an existing object, you would have to use the `destination` parameter and just update it, although this doesn't make much sense for `Uri` specifically.

Then you just map your classes like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {

    cfg.CreateMap<string, Uri>().ConvertUsing<StringToUriConverter>();

    cfg.CreateMap<A, B>();
});

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

The idea here is if you have any other mappings where you need to convert a string to an Uri, AutoMapper now already knows how to do so, you don't need to explicitly use `.ForMember`, nor `.AfterMap` anymore.

Here you are the [docs for AutoMapper ITypeConverter](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html).

Answer (score 1):

A more reusable way would be to define a general mapping from `string` to `Uri`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<string, Uri>().ConvertUsing<StringToUriConverter>();

private class StringToUriConverter: TypeConverter<string, Uri> {
    protected override Uri ConvertCore(string source) {
        Uri uri;
        Uri.TryCreate(source, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);
        return uri;
    }
}
```

Then your actual mapping simplifies to

```
cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.URI, o => o.Mapfrom(src => src.URI));
```

Automapper will recognize that it has to map from `string URI` to `Uri URI` and will apply the mapping `string -> Uri` we defined above.

See also [Automapper docs - Custom Type Converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Custom-type-converters.md).

Comment: The properties have the same name, there is no need to map explicitly (the MapFrom).

Comment: Right, I just added the `ForMember` to show that nothing special must be done for this member. `cfg.CreateMap<A, B>();` would be sufficient.